# Uploading the .hex file from ArduinoIDe with a raspberry pi to an attiny85

Tags: c, arduino, raspberry-pi, hex, avr

I, i'm programming an attiny85. First i did it with my raspberry pi and it was ok to make a programm that turn on/turn off the led connected to my attiny85. But there is just a fex tutorial on the net to programm attiny with raspberry pi but there is many one with Arduino . So i decided to use the arduino ide, then get the .hex file and upload it on the attiny with my raspberry pi. ( i don't have arduino board ). More over the arduino ide has many library that make your life simple. But when i upload it everything is ok but the programm seems not working. I don't really know if that's possible to create the .hex file with arduino and push with Raspberry pi.
Ps: Sorry english is not my native language
Here the first programm i made with raspberry and who works :

```
#define F_CPU 1000000L
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
int main(void)
 {

    PORTB = 0xFF;   // LED's are off

  for (;;) {

     DDRB = 1<<DDB4 | 1<<DDB1 | 1<<DDB0 | 1<<DDB3;
    //PORTB ^= 0xFF;   // invert all the pins
     _delay_ms(1000); // wait some time
     DDRB = 0<<DDB4 | 0<<DDB1 | 0<<DDB0 | 0<<DDB3;
     _delay_ms(1000); // wait some time

   }
   return 0;
}
```

And then the programm i made with arduino ( i know it's only should turn on 2 led but none are on ) :

```
void setup() {

 pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(2, OUTPUT);

}


void loop() {
  digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  delay(1000);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);  // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);              // wait for a second
}
```

And to push it i use this command ( for both programm, but for the first one i compile it first to generate the.hex ):

```
sudo gpio -g mode 22 out
sudo gpio -g write 22 0
sudo /usr/local/bin/avrdude -p t85 -P /dev/spidev0.0 -c linuxspi -b 10000 -U flash:w:blinky.hex
```

So is it normal ? Is this a code problem or i can't do what i try ? 
I really want use arduino IDE because i want my attiny/rasbperry communicate by serial gpio

Comment: I think the baud rate of 10000 is not correct. Try the typical baud rates like 9600 or 115200.

Comment: I try for the first code and it's also work but for the IDE Arduino code, i does not work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it's work ! :D
In fact to compile/push the blinky.c i was using a makefile ( i found it on a tuto ). 
So now i just take the .hex and use " make install ", as i did with the first blinky but without the compilation as i get the .hex and not the .c
So here the makefile :)

```
MCU=attiny85
AVRDUDEMCU=t85
CC=/usr/bin/avr-gcc
CFLAGS=-g -Os -Wall -mcall-prologues -mmcu=$(MCU)
OBJ2HEX=/usr/bin/avr-objcopy
AVRDUDE=/usr/local/bin/avrdude
TARGET=arduiblinky
# target = name of your file you want upload on the attiny

all : 
# no need this part if you have the .hex :D
    #$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(TARGET).c -o $(TARGET)
    #$(OBJ2HEX) -R .eeprom -O ihex $(TARGET) $(TARGET).hex
    #rm -f $(TARGET)

install : all
    sudo gpio -g mode 22 out
    sudo gpio -g write 22 0
    sudo $(AVRDUDE) -p $(AVRDUDEMCU) -P /dev/spidev0.0 -c linuxspi -b 9600 - U flash:w:$(TARGET).hex
    sudo gpio -g write 22 1

noreset : all
    sudo $(AVRDUDE) -p $(AVRDUDEMCU) -P /dev/spidev0.0 -c linuxspi -b 10000 -U flash:w:$(TARGET).hex

fuse :
    sudo gpio -g mode 22 out
    sudo gpio -g write 22 0
    sudo $(AVRDUDE) -p $(AVRDUDEMCU) -P /dev/spidev0.0 -c linuxspi -b 10000 -U lfuse:w:0x62:m -U hfuse:w:0xdf:m -U efuse:w:0xff:m 
    sudo gpio -g write 22 1

clean :
    rm -f *.hex *.obj *.o
```

But does someone can explain me why it's work when i use the make file and why it's does not work when i do that :

```
sudo gpio -g mode 22 out
sudo gpio -g write 22 0
sudo /usr/local/bin/avrdude -p t85 -P /dev/spidev0.0 -c linuxspi -b 10000 -U flash:w:blinky.hex
```

Thanks and i hope it could help someone :)

Comment: I find it ! When i was not using the make file, i forget to write that :
---->  sudo gpio -g write 22 1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look about using the arduino library and add it to your project. Then when you use the avr gcc compiler, you add the library. But it seems strange that your second code is not working on the attiny. Did you check that the .hex file contained hexadecimal code ? :)

Comment: Ok i will try to add arduino library but i still don't know if it should work or no